# Share a scope between Jersey Servlet and JSF Backing Bean

Tags: jsf, jersey, java-ee-6, cdi

I just want to ask if anybody has done something like this. Basically, it's like paypal express checkout functionality:

1.) You select item for checkout in merchant store.

2.) You will be redirected to a login page, in my case I implemented it as a Jersey Rest Servlet. On post, store the data in a session EJB backing bean and invoke Response.seeOther() to redirect to the login page (JSF).

3.) If the login is successful the posted transaction data should be persisted.

But it seems, while I can invoke the session backing bean, store the posted data in a variable inside that bean. When I click login (login ok) and I re-access the same bean, the variable where I store the posted data becomes null.

So is session scope not shared between Jersey Rest Servlet and Session scope backing bean in ejb?

Any other good approach?

Thanks,

czetsuya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying to solve this problem, I've come to a conclusion that it's not possible to share jsf session to jersey or servlet session because they are implemented in a different way.

My solution to my problem (not answer to the question) is to use HttpServlet, and store the transaction as a session attribute:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
session.setAttribute("POSTED_ITEMS", postedItems);
```

So I'll be able to access it to the next page.

*I wish there's a way to post to a jsf page backed by javaee6 bean, that'll make life simple :-).

Answer (score 1):

Session scope is not available for web service calls. You'd need to use Application scope, or create your own.

Comment: I see, now that's clarified. Unfortunately Application Scope seems not a good idea, as I can have several checkout transactions at the same time and I don't want to store the posted data in 1 application scope variable.

Comment: That's what maps are designed for (and that's certainly how an application server internally handles parallel sessions... :-) Another option would be to store the data in the database, but then you might have to fiddle with cancelled logins.

Comment: Unfortunately, although database is the simplest approach it might not be the best option since garbage data will just pile up in the database. I'm not too sure with maps, as I haven't implemented this type of functionality before. So it's like I'll have a map of orders that will be binded to users (1 to 1)?